# (PyQT) How do I get which element triggered a callback function when many elements are connected to that callback function?

Tags: python, pyqt

my code looks something like this:

```py
for i in range(num_boxes):
    box = QCheckBox(self.row)
    box.setObjectName(f"{i}")
    box.setText(f"{i}")
    box.stateChanged.connect(checkbox_callback)
```

So I dynamically generate checkboxes and link them all up to a single callback function which looks something like this:

```py
def checkbox_callback(state):
    print(state)
```

I am now wondering how I can check which of my checkboxes has triggered the callback function, because to my knowledge, I can only get the *state* of the box that triggered the event, but not the box itself, which is mandatory for my purposes.

I hope I made myself clear and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way is to pass the widget as part of the callback.

```
from functools import partial

for i in range(num_boxes):
    box = QCheckBox(self.row)
    box.setObjectName(f"{i}")
    box.setText(f"{i}")
    box.stateChanged.connect(partial(checkbox_callback, widget=box))

def checkbox_callback(state, widget):
    print(widget.text(), state)
```

Alternatively you could subclass the widget to make a custom signal.

```
class MyCheckBox(QCheckBox):

    customStateChanged = Signal(QCheckBox, Qt.CheckState)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.stateChanged.connect(self.onStateChange)
    
    @Slot(Qt.CheckState)
    def onStateChange(self, checkState):
        self.customStateChanged.emit(self, checkState)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to do this using a lambda, which didnt work out. What does partial do?

Comment: Lambdas don't work in loops unless you specifically pass in the value (eg. `lambda: fn(box)` is wrong, but `lambda box=box: fn(box)` is correct, but ugly). Partial is just creating an uncalled function with some arguments already given.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have seen the box=box "trick" before, but I was not able to get that to work. I think from now on, I will be using the partial method because it looks more convenient. Thanks again!

Comment: @LucaTatas if it didn't work, it's probably because you didn't consider the signal argument; the `stateChanged` signal has the *state* argument, and if you use `lambda box=box: fn(box)`, the box *keyword* will have the *state* as its value; for these situations, the keyworderd arguments should be *added* to the existing arguments of the signal: `lambda state, box=box: fn(box)`.

Comment: There's also another possibility: functions invoked by a signal can also use [`sender()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender), which returns the object that *emitted* the signal. So, in `checkbox_callback` you can do `checkbox = self.sender()` to get the checkbox that called it. Please note that: 1. if signals are concatenated, `sender` refers to the "last" signal: if you connect the signal A of object B to the signal X of object Y and the signal X to a function Z, using `self.sender()` in Z will return Y, not B; 2. `sender` should be used with care, read the notes in the docs linked above.